# Deploying Streamlit App in Azure without using Docker

Tags: azure, deployment, streamlit

Is there a way to deploy Streamlit App on Azure App Service without using Docker?
All the guides in the internet refer to Docker virtualization whereas in theory, the Azure Web App should be able deploy the code automatically from Azure Repo. I used “streamlit run app.py” as a startup command in the Azure configuration tab, but nothing really happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can build this out by setting up a normal Steamlit app and throw in the App Service specific configurations to get this going. Here are the exact steps:

1. Create Azure App service with pricing tier B1 or higher. Free version(F1) doesnt support websocket which is required for Streamlit.
2. Create a folder for the project. And add `requirements.txt` with following content.

   streamlit
3. Deploy this folder to Azure app service.
4. Make the following configuration change. Under `Configuration > General Settings > Startup command` provide the following value

   python -m streamlit hello --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0
5. Enable Web Scockets in the Azure App service configuration.

> Azure only allows pip binaries to run when used as modules instead of directly.
> We are mentioning port beacuse by default the service listens to port 8000.  We are mentioning the server.address as 0.0.0.0 so that the it can serve all the incoming request from azure infra.

[image]

Comment: with the example works but when I tried to do it with my app unfortunately it does not work. I just changed "hello" through the name of the app. I receive the following error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'portalUrl')"

Comment: Can you upload the example deployment somewhere for me to look?

Comment: I can not see `Enable Web Scockets` option. Some people say I must use Windows os, but it is not available for python3. I did choose `B1` tier. Streamlit is launching but stuck in `Please wait` inside Streamlit interface

Answer (score 0):

To use this to run your app you need to replace "hello" with "run app.py" (assuming the application name is app.py). For me this worked when I put my code on gitHub and signed in, but I failed both when I deployed via VSCode with Azure extensions, or via gitlab. When I did exactly according to this video it worked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2toRzAYT8yo.